# A resource for wearable data?

Tags: data-request, computing

Anyone know of a good resource(s) for data collected from wearables? Phone information in terms of location and motion is an obvious one, but where would such data reside that is in anonymized form and is open to the public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kaggle had a competition that involved "biometric data," which came from sensors in people's cell phones.  The data is available at http://www.kaggle.com/c/accelerometer-biometric-competition/data

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this project:

[OpenPaths](https://openpaths.cc)

[image]

Comment: This is a great resource, but the Kaggle link is the most relevant answer to the question.